# React native onEndReached always fire when 1st row is rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase `child_added` to list out data. Every time first row is rendered, `onEndReached` is fired. Any wrong with my code?

Component

```
onEndedReached() {
 lastkey = Object.keys(this.props.contacts).pop();
 // this.props.nextPage(this.props.auth.uid, lastKey);
 console.log('Fire onEndedReached:', lastkey);
}

render() {
 return (
  <ListView
    style={styles.container}
    enableEmptySections
    dataSource={this.dataSource}
    renderRow={this.renderRow}
    onEndReachedThreshold={50}
    onEndReached={() => this.onEndedReached()}
  />
 )
 }
}
```

Action

```
export const getContacts = (uid) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref(`userContacts/${uid}`)
      .limitToFirst(20).on('child_added', (contact) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS,
        payload: { [contact.key]: contact.val() }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_CONTACTS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, action.payload );
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you use Scroll view as a container for listview ?

Comment: No. i idid not use

Comment: they changed the behavior on version >= 0.36; just add safeguards on your `onEndReached` function when you dont want it to fire.

Comment: @jan what does safeguards mean?

Comment: i see, i will try later.

Comment: @Jan it works.  Thank you. Can you put in answer so i can mark it

Comment: here you go buddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just add safeguards on your onEndReached function when you dont want it to fire.

for example. when you are refreshing the listview or while it is getting data or the length of your current data does not meet your requirements to trigger endReached. put all of this in state too.

```
if( this.state.isEndCountZero || this.state.skip < 15 || this.state.onEndReached || this.state.refreshing || this.state.isLoading) { return; }
```

Comment: For datastores you can test `dataStore.getRowCount(0)`.

Comment: It's strange but i got error when i try to use this things, may be i should import sometings

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention for **onEndReachedThreshold** parameter.

> How far from the end (in units of visible length of the list) the
>   bottom edge of the list must be from the end of the content to trigger
>   the onEndReached callback. Thus a value of 0.5 will trigger
>   onEndReached when the end of the content is within half the visible
>   length of the list.

Maybe you should set it a less number.